# How to move from one Activity to another after creating the first instance of them?

Tags: android

I have `MainActivity.java` and I want to open from it `Activity A`.

Assuming I'm opening `Activity` `A` from `MainActivity`, i'll use this code :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,A.class);
startActivity(i);
```

When i'm in Activity A, and I press the back button. The back button will finish **Activity A** and go back to **MainActivity**. So If I relaunch **Activity A**, it will be relaunched from the beginning. This is not what I want. I want only a single instance to be created from **Activity A** so if I move from **A** to **MainActivity** as many times as I want , it will not be relaunched, it will keep the last state.

Comment: just wondering that shouldn't the intent have `A.class` as the second parameter instead of `A.java`?

Comment: you're right i'm sorry I corrected it

Comment: you can directly call finish().

Comment: but if I call finish, it will close the actual activity leaving the one reordered to front active and it will not close it.

Answer (score 1):

**When the MainActiivty starts another, the new activity ,Activity A is pushed on the top of the stack and takes focus**. **The previous activity remains in the stack, but is stopped**. **When an activity stops, the system retains the current state of its user interface.**

When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is **popped from the top of the stack (the activity is destroyed) and the previous activity resumes (the previous state of its UI is restored)**. Activities in the stack are never rearranged, only pushed and popped from the stack—pushed onto the stack when started by the current activity and popped off when the user leaves it using the Back button. As such, the back stack operates as a "last in, first out" object structure.

Note : Multiple tasks can be held in the background at once. However, if the user is running many background tasks at the same time, the system might begin destroying background activities in order to recover memory, causing the activity states to be lost.

In your MainActivity to Activity A and press back Button , Activity A is paopped form stack and destroyed.

Again from MainActivty navigate to A, activity is recreated since it was destroyed. This is how it works.

For more details have a look at the back stack in the following link.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

```
  android:launchMode
```

An instruction on how the activity should be launched. There are four modes that work in conjunction with activity flags (FLAG_ACTIVITY_* constants) in Intent objects to determine what should happen when the activity is called upon to handle an intent.

They are:

1. standard
2. singleTop
3. singleTask
4. singleInstance

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode.

But once activity is destroyed and you need to navigate to that activity, that activity is recreated.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! So you are saying that I cannot achieve what I want using `Intent`s. Should I use `Tab`s instead?